# Get data from Cursor: null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-cursor

I've this two classes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        String[] temp = new String[] { "40", "35", "28" };
        String[] hum = new String[] { "50%", "30%", "80%" };
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            helper.insertRecord(temp[i], hum[i]);
        }
        Cursor c = helper.getData();
        String res = "";
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
                res+=c.getString(0)+" "+c.getString(1)+"\n";
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            c.close();
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(res);
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "database_name";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "my_table";
    private static final String COL_TEMPERATURA = "temperatura";
    private static final String COL_UMIDITA = "umidita";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 33);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_TEMPERATURA
                + " TEXT, " + COL_UMIDITA + " TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void insertRecord(String temperatura, String umidita) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TEMPERATURA, temperatura);
        cv.put(COL_UMIDITA, umidita);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        db.close();

    }

    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] cols = new String[]{COL_TEMPERATURA, COL_UMIDITA};
        Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
        return res;
    }

}
```

but whew i execute my code, i have a nullpointer exception on MainActivity when i call 
    tv.setText(res);

why?

Log:

```
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at com.example.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-08 19:25:16.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5911):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a `TextView` called `tv` in your `activity_main.xml` ?

Comment: sure, i've used eclipse auto-completion

Comment: And you're sure the NullPointerException is at this exact line ? Could you post the logcat ?

Comment: posted. MainActivity java 31 it's exactly tv.setText row

Comment: can you add your xml layout file?

Comment: Did you try to move `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);` `tv.setText(res);` before in your code (after `setContentView`) to be sure that was the problem ? And try replacing `res` by something else. You can also try to clean your project

Answer (score 0):

you must test if your cursor c is not empty:

```
 Cursor c = helper.getData();
    String res = "";
    if(c.moveToFirst() && c.getCount() != 0) {
        while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
            res+=c.getString(0)+" "+c.getString(1)+"\n";
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
    }
```

Comment: I obtain the same error. How cursor could be empty? i write the query for retrieve all data inside database i've previous insert

Comment: if nothing has been returned in the query, it returns null. if you have a previous insert so your query is false. have you tested your query separately?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to set breakpoint on line:

```
if(c.moveToFirst()) {
```

and see what happens with variables "c" and "res" after step over. This should provide you enough info to determine what is happening.

To be absolutely sure that "tv" is initialized, try to set:

```
tv.setText("test");
```

just to be sure that "tv" is not null.

Comment: i've solved. The problem was that eclipse doesn't initialized textview for some reason that i don't know. I've restarted IDE and everithing goes fine